# RStudio: Where to store quantmod package

Tags: r, quantmod, yahoo-finance

I get the error when I try to get data from Yahoo Finance with the `getSymbols` command. It seems that something wrong in the paths of storing packages. Anyway to fix it?

```
> install.packages("quantmod")
Installing package into ‘/Users/yihuan/Library/R/3.1/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  
Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  456k  100  456k    0     0  3850k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 3867k

The downloaded binary packages are in
/var/folders/p4/d1716x613c70sd0wq1r6hy3m0000gn/T//RtmpOaKkBC/downloaded_packages

> library(quantmod)
> DOW30 = getSymbols("^DJI",from = "2016-01-01",to = "2016-12-31" ,auto.assign = F)
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("DJI.Open", "DJI.High", "DJI.Low",  : 
length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
In addition: Warning message:
In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on '/var/folders/p4/d1716x613c70sd0wq1r6hy3m0000gn/T//RtmpOaKkBC/file43e4278a37cf'
```

The session info added below:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] quantmod_0.4-5 TTR_0.23-0     xts_0.9-7      zoo_1.7-12    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.1.2      lattice_0.20-33 tools_3.1.2     yaml_2.1.13
```

Comment: This runs without error for me. Please include more information (`sessionInfo()`, to start).

Comment: Try to update R and quantmod